# How to find out the device Coordinates

Tags: ios4, core-location

Hi friends I am new iPhone developer. How to find out the device coordinates using GPS map. I tried this delegate method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation;


- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location 
{
locationLabel.text = [location description];

NSLog(@"the locationLabel.text %@",locationLabel.text);
}
```

But error is device coordinate is working with simulator successfully But device not working this kind of error is coming what is the reason please help me

> The identify used to sign the executable is no longer valid.
>
> Please verify that your device's clock is properly set,and that your signing certificate is not expired.(0XE8008018).

Answer (score 1):

your's debug it on simulator only if you don't have iPhone Developer certificate. check on left corner in xcode you select simulator not device.